# TestNG and cucumber for integration testing

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm, testng-dataprovider

We are using TestNG for integration testing. is it possible to use the cucumber feature file layer on top of the testNG testcases to have the traceability of test scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is Yes. Here is [example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng) from Cucumber folks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although TestNG is in that scenario used more as a technical layer below Cucumber to run tests, rather than key component of test automation framework (as it is when it is used without Cucumber). You may find this post beneficial:

[Reading parameter values from Testng.xml file in cucumber stepdefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924000/reading-parameter-values-from-testng-xml-file-in-cucumber-stepdefs/31950337#31950337)